# Get object record with unique field from list

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, map, list

I want to remove People__c record from list based on field value I have list of custom object People__c  with field Responsible__c which is another object id. I am getting list of id and want to get  something like below code.

```
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>('1','2','3');
List<People__c> peoples  =  Select id,name  from People__c Where Responsible__c: = ids[0] ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1
List<People__c> peoples1 =  Select id,name  from People__c Where Responsible__c: = ids[1] ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1
List<People__c> peoples2 =  Select id,name from People__c Where Responsible__c =: ids[2] ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1
```

So maybe I must do something like that? But I don't know how. So if in List there are elements 'Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4' it must return one record with Test1, one with Test2 and so on. Even if reocrds with Test1 more than 1.

```
List<People__c> peoples  =  Select id,name  from People__c Where Responsible__c in :ids ORDER BY Name 
Map<Id,People__c> peopleMap = new Map<Id,People__c>();
for(People__c p : peoples) {
Map.put();
//add only one people for each element in list where responsible__c = each element from list.
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). What exact error or result did you get after running the code? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357621/edit) you question to add that information.

Comment: @Moonpie i dont get result or error cause i dont know what to do in last part.

Comment: We appreciate that you have included some code - which is more than many first time posters - but this site still exists to help you to *help yourself*. You should attempt to run your code in a dev org or sandbox (anonymous Apex is fine), then see your result and/or error & try to correct it. If you get to a point where you cannot move forward, come back, edit your question to include updated code & any *exact* error or result. SFSE is not a code writing or implementation service. To be honest, it seems to me that you should first do some Trailhead modules on Apex.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are moving in the correct direction, you should use `Map`, where the key is a unique id from list `ids`. This could be rephrased, as "I want to group selected records by specific field values, size of this group should be 1 record".

```
List<People__c> peoples  =  [
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM People__c
    WHERE Responsible__c IN :ids
    ORDER BY Name
];

Map<Id, People__c> peopleMap = new Map<Id, People__c>();
for(People__c p : peoples) {
    if(!peopleMap.containsKey(p.Responsible__c)){
        peopleMap.put(p.Responsible__c, p);
    }
}
```

as a result, you will have `Map` `peopleMap`, where key is a `Responsible__c` `Id` and value is a `People__c` record

Comment: Looks good,  thanks. But also i need People__c.id. Is it only way and i just must get that id from People__c in map?

Comment: you can get it as `peopleMap.get(someID).Id`